# In Unity how to save an image in a Google Photos public album

Tags: api, unity-game-engine, photo

I have a screenshot, and I want to put it in an already created public album on Google Photos. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: nope, I've solved uploading the image on an image hosting service

Comment: Its unfortunate that the Goggle Photos API don't support uploading to already created albums. I did provide you with an answer to that though. If all you want to do is upload, like I suggested you can do it on Google photos still, just not on a already created album.

Answer (score 0):

To start there is no special Google photos API for Unity.

Now on the [google photos documentation](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/manage-albums) says you can't upload to an already existing album.

> Note that you can only add media items that have been uploaded by your application to albums that your application has created.

I have looked into the issue tracker and this is a much awaited feature with no apparent interest from google to support.

If you dont require upload to a particular existing album, you can create an album via your unity app and then upload your photos there.